# How to pass from a binary char array to int array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have this array "m":

```
m = ['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '1111']
```

How could I use a lambda function to change its format to:

```
n1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

or to:

```
n2 = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
```

?

Comment: `[int(x) for x in '12345']` will get you the inner array.

Comment: You can create n2 with list comprehensions: `n2 = [[int(char_i) for char_i in char] for char in m]`

Comment: `n0 = [list(item) for item in m]; n1 = [int(i) for lst in n0 for i in lst]; n2 = [[int(i) for i in lst] for lst in n0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m = ['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '1111']
funct = lambda m: [int(x) for x in ''.join(m)];
```

This will express list "m" as list "n1" with a lambda function as requested.

Comment: Could I do it without loop? Maybe lambda function

Comment: n1 = [int(x) for x in ''.join(m)]

Comment: funct = lambda m: [int(x) for x in ''.join(m)];